# Using Flutter Engine in Flutter apps: is it possible?

Tags: flutter, flutter-engine

I have a macOS app in Flutter inside which I would like to have a Flutter Engine running to render another Flutter app.

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is using the AOT compiler to release my macOS app, inside which I want to use JIT & Flutter Engine to render another flutter app at runtime.

All docs I've read talk about how to use the Flutter Engine inside iOS/Android apps, but not into Flutter itself; any clue on how to include a Flutter Engine in a Flutter app?